# Django template errors

Tags: python, django, templates

Basically it is a view of testing app for booking purposes:

```
def bookingform(request):
    form = BookingForm()
    return render_to_response('book/bookingform.html',{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

While running this app an error of the form is given:

> Need more than 1 value to unpack.
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in find_template_loader
>   94.         module, attr = loader.rsplit('.', 1)

Can anybody explain what it actually means and how to resolve it?

Comment: No, not without seeing the actual error and full traceback, plus the actual bit of code causing the error (hint: it isn't this bit).

Comment: can you show your settings for `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` ?

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean?

```
x, y = somethingiterable()
```

Somethingiterable has to return at least two values here or there will be an exception raised

```
module, attr = loader.rsplit('.', 1)
```

Older versions of django would just start iterating on whatever `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` was set to. If it was a string then it would try the first letter in the name of your template loader and fail here because there is not going to be a dot in it. Lack of dot means rsplit() will not return more than 1 value which means attr never gets set and then you have an exception.

Change how you are setting `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` to be like below with the `()`. You can specify multiple with commas. Take a look at any other settings that are named plurally, they might want this format as well so you should find a sample settings.py for your version of python and double check.

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = ( #open paren
   'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader', 
) #close paren
```